# Can the OS kill the process randomly in Linux?

Tags: shutdown

One of our processes went down in a Linux box. When I checked in logs, I could see it was shut down. That shows graceful shutdown. I checked CPU, Memory, process utilization, all under threshold. There were no abnormalities found over memory utilization. Is there any way that OS killed the process randomly?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel can kill a process under extreme circumstances ie memory starvation. But since this was not the case, and you are sure that sysads did not kill the process either. The shutdown must have been initiated from within the process.

Linux would not kill your process unless there are extreme circumstances. Although, some other process running under root might be able to send such signals.

You should get more idea from the kernal logs and make sure that was the process killed by OS itself or not.

Comment: I checked the logs of the process, seems it has not brought down himself. I checked the kernel logs, no activity recorded during that particular time. So its clear that OS has not initiated the kill command. Something else happened. Any idea that process shutdown gracefully ?? like memory issue, is there anything else we can check ?

Comment: See machine access logs at the time of shutdown. It might have been a person. Nothing else to check left. Something from inside the program, some bug, thats all.

Comment: Any idea, where the machine access logs would be stored in linux ?